# CSS code fornav menu background on mobile

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I am currently working on - https://flyboats.tech

I am using Elementskit nav builder I want to set the background color for the mobile and tablet device nav menu to black

Code that already exsit is this :

```css
    margin-top: 6px;
}
@media (max-width: 1024px){
    .ekit_menu_responsive_tablet .elementskit-submenu-indicator {
        border: 1px solid transparent !important;
    }
}
body, .dark-mode .ts-author-media, .dark-mode .ts-author-content::before, .dark-mode .ts-author-content::after, .dark-mode .post-layout-style4 .post-single .entry-header {
   background-color: black;
}
```

Comment: As a reminder, the Wordpress tag is for programming-specific questions about the WordPress content management system.

Answer (score 0):

Check the pixels for phone and tablets. See what's the max pixel (example: 991px) then just say which exact part you want to change or just add a class for that black background color.

Example: color-bl. and use `background-color:black !important;` you want to change color of many classes. Instead of this try to change one class and how to reverse it? Simple you don't even need to. Those media queries only work after or before the given pixels. But don't use any `!important` in other classes of elements which has color-bl